# how to upload and retive a file from asp.net webpageto SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

Can any one help how to create Console Application(or any other method ) to upload and retive a file from asp.net webpageto SharePoint 2010. is there are other method to achive the goal
my requireemnt is the end user will update the docuemts via asp.net site it, all the uploaded documents will store in sharepoint via asp.net page.
 kindly guide how to achive it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Client object model for this.

For more details check following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

The link is for 2013 but same is valid for 2010

Also you can check for 2010 specific:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/04/24/how-to-download-a-document-from-sharepoint-2010-using-client-context-object-model/